# Query Extended Event from TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have extended event like,

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Name] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(SET collect_statement=(1)
    ACTION(...)
    ......
```

Now when I right-click and `View Target Data` it tries to load everything, even the filter is there. I just need to see statements executed today. How can I get today statemnets?

Comment: What you mean, " the filter is there", have you set a filter in Extended Events/Filters menu of SSMS?

Comment: From UI I can filter the date. But the UI keeps bringing all records instead of just that day records.

Comment: If you've set extended events filter in SSMS UI and SSMS still ignores the filter i thing you should contact MS support. It works for me - events are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT event_data = CONVERT(XML, event_data)
```

INTO #t
  FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

I use below commands for this case. If you use older version than SQL Server 2016, you should change **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS** statement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempapperror
SELECT   
            [timestamp] = (xe_file.xml_data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', '[varchar](100)' ) )
            ,[database_name] = (xe_file.xml_data.value('(/event/action[@name=''database_name'']/value)[1]','[varchar](250)'))
            ,...
            INTO #tempapperror
    FROM    (
                SELECT   [FILE_NAME]
                        ,[XML_DATA] = CONVERT(XML, EVENT_DATA)
                FROM    sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('yourfilepath*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
            ) AS xe_file
    WHERE (xe_file.xml_data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', '[varchar](100)' ) )>='2019-07-17T00:00:00.000Z'

SELECT * FROM #tempapperror  ORDER BY 1 DESC
```